# Liferay Document and Media limitations

Tags: performance, liferay

I'm working on an EDM migration project and I would like to know if anyone has information on the documents limitation in Liferay 6.2 CE.

We need to import millions of documents to a Liferay instance.
I would like to know if someone has done that with a community edition ? And if someone knows if I need a cluster of Liferay's to keep an acceptable response time for the end users.

Thanks for your advices !
Julien

Comment: I'm voting to close this question here, as it's not [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow. You might get better help on the Liferay forums. However, you'll need to add more information there: Scalability is not so much about the number of documents stored, but their access pattern (and potential size, as the download might run long time for big files). A million document with a handful of users is something different than 10000 documents for 10000 *concurrent* users. Note that there are no more updates for Liferay 6.2.x CE

Comment: Hi Olaf, I just wanted to see if somone has used Liferay Comminty Edition to store millions of files. I don't mind about scability for now ^^ juste hoping Liferay can handle that amount. I'll go to Liferay forums. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in the Liferay documentation. https://dev.liferay.com/fr/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/document-repository-configuration

> The advanced file system store overcomes this limitation by programmatically creating a structure that can expand to millions of files, by alphabetically nesting the files in folders. This not only allows for more files to be stored, but also improves performance as there are fewer files stored per folder.

So it seems that with this advanced file system store, Liferay can handle millions of documents and bypass OS limitations.

Hope this helps other.

Julien